# Display Wordpress home posts in 3 columns?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Bootstrap based starter theme "Understrap", which incorporates bootsrap into Underscores.

My goal would be to display my latest posts on the front page in three columns horizontally, so:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
...
```

I'm a beginner, so i'm having a hard time figuring out how to approach this with Understrap.

My Index.php code is shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

get_header();

$container   = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
$sidebar_pos = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_sidebar_position' );
?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/hero', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-index">

    <div class="<?php echo esc_html( $container ); ?>" id="content" tabindex="-1">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Do the left sidebar check and opens the primary div -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/left-sidebar-check', 'none' ); ?>

            <main class="site-main" id="main">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php

                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );
                        ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->

            <!-- The pagination component -->
            <?php understrap_pagination(); ?>

        </div><!-- #primary -->

        <!-- Do the right sidebar check -->
        <?php if ( 'right' === $sidebar_pos || 'both' === $sidebar_pos ) : ?>

            <?php get_sidebar( 'right' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .row -->

</div><!-- Container end -->

</div><!-- Wrapper end -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row / columns class from Bootstrap, and a counter ($i) to restart a row after 3 columns. Here is a idea of changes based on your code :

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

get_header();

$container   = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
$sidebar_pos = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_sidebar_position' );
?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/hero', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-index">

    <div class="<?php echo esc_html( $container ); ?>" id="content" tabindex="-1">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Do the left sidebar check and opens the primary div -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'global-templates/left-sidebar-check', 'none' ); ?>

            <main class="site-main" id="main">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                  <?php $i = 1; ?>

                  <div class="row">

                    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">

                        <?php
                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );
                        ?>

                      </div><!-- /.col -->

                      <?php
                      if( $i == 3 ){
                        echo '</div><div class="row">';
                        $i = 0;
                      }
                      $i++;
                      ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                  </div><!-- /.row -->

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->

            <!-- The pagination component -->
            <?php understrap_pagination(); ?>

        </div><!-- #primary -->

        <!-- Do the right sidebar check -->
        <?php if ( 'right' === $sidebar_pos || 'both' === $sidebar_pos ) : ?>

            <?php get_sidebar( 'right' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .row -->

</div><!-- Container end -->

</div><!-- Wrapper end -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope I will help !

Comment: Yes! Thank you so very much for your help! :)

Comment: @Slayton No problem ;)